# Counting number of Class Instances using "private static integer variable" in c++

Tags: c++

I tried to count the number of instances of a class using :

```
class shelf
{
private:
    static int count_instances = 0 ;
    book b1;
public :
shelf() {
    count_instances++;
    cout << "this is the "<<count_instances<<" instance"<<endl;
}
};
main (){
shelf s1;
}
```

but get the compilation error :
ISO c++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member.

While the following arrangement seems to work

```
class shelf
{
private:
    static int count_instances ;
    book b1;
public :
shelf() {
    count_instances++;
    cout << "this is the "<<count_instances<<" instance"<<endl;
}
};
int shelf::count_instances =0;

main (){
shelf s1;
}
```

Can someone help me understand? Also what is the right way to count the number of instances of a class

Comment: What is the question?  You already have the solution

Comment: int shelf::count_instances =0; Shouldn't this access be disallowed?

Comment: _"Can someone help me understand?"_  That's too broad a question.  Can you ask specifically about what you do not understand?

Comment: The first is the declaration that the variable will exist ... the second creates a version of it.  That's just what the syntax is.

Comment: oh, So the static private members can be accessed from outside the class?

Comment: You've got it 100% right, there's nothing else to "understand" here :-) Make sure `int shelf::count_instances =0;` definition is in a CPP file, not in the header.

Comment: @Agent007 You are not accessing private member outside the class, you are providing its definition outside class header, as required by the standard.

Comment: As for counting instances of the class, your attempt fails to count copy-initialized instances.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight , That makes sense. Thanks!